# using Resources Importer

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

I am trying to use Resources Importer tools , to migrate my templates and structures from an old Liferay to new one since Lar's files do not work with multiple versions.

Anyone can help me how I can use this tool, the documentation is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the following documentation? https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/status-of-resource-importer

Can you specify what's not clear to you? You simply copy your assets in the correct directory and it should work.

Please not that the resource importer is deprecated with no direct replacement https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/status-of-resource-importer